# Next JS and Redux: getInitialProps not returning props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering

Need a react pro to help me out here. Thanks in advance!

I am trying to find a sweet spot to use redux and NEXT JS without making the setup too complicated.

> **GOAL** : is to make use of getInitialProps(for SSR) to dispatch actions (especially the ones which involve API requests) so that the data is pre loaded and SSR'ed.

To achieve this, I have done this setup:

> **_app component** :

```js
// to connect redux with react 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// REDUCER
import reducers from '../redux/reducers';

// STORE
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const AppComponent = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    )
}

AppComponent.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    let pageProps = {};
    if (appContext.Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await appContext.Component.getInitialProps(appContext.ctx);
    };
    return { ...pageProps }
}

// returns a new instance of store everytime its called
const makeStore = () => store;
const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);

export default wrapper.withRedux(AppComponent);
```

> **Landing Page (pages/index.js)** :

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../redux/actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

const LandingPage = ({ posts }) => {

    console.log('POSTS', posts); // <-- NOT getting posts for some reason via GIPs() !!!

    return <h1>Home page</h1>
}

LandingPage.getInitialProps = async (ctx, { store }) => {
    await store.dispatch(fetchPosts());
    const posts = await store.getState().posts;
    console.log('RETURNING POSTS', posts) // <-- this returns the list of posts
    return { ...posts }
}

export default LandingPage;
```

> **Actions**:

```js
// custom axios function
import api from '../../api';

export const fetchPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    const response = await api.get('/posts');
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_POSTS',
        payload: response.data
    });
};
```

**ISSUE**: Event though the getInitialProps() is console loggin the list of POSTS, I am unable to retrieve the POSTS from the getInitialProps to the LandingPage component.
When I console log the posts or even props for that matter, it shows undefined.

Is there a better way of doing this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The object that is returned from the `getInitialProps` will be merge to the `props` of the component. So, you might want to remove your destructuring operator in your `LandingPage` and `AppComponent` `getInitialProps` function:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../redux/actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

const LandingPage = ({ posts }) => { // <-- destructuring "posts" property from props object

    console.log('POSTS', posts); // <-- posts should be available here

    return <h1>Home page</h1>
}

LandingPage.getInitialProps = async (ctx, { store }) => {
    await store.dispatch(fetchPosts());
    const posts = await store.getState().posts;
    console.log('RETURNING POSTS', posts) // <-- this returns the list of posts
    return { posts }; // <-- return an object with "posts" property
}

export default LandingPage;
```

Comment: I tried that initially and after your comment as well. It is not working.

Comment: Have you remove the destructuring operator in AppComponent also?  `return {pageProps}`

Comment: Did you end up solving this, and how? I think I'm running across the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

## 2022 answer (with TypeScript):

To achieve this with TypeScript + Redux (from `App.tsx` to make it available on all pages), the syntax would be similar to:

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = customWrapper.getInitialAppProps(
  (store) => async (appContext) => {
    const response = await getAuthInfo();

    if ((response as any)?.error) {
      store.dispatch(setAuthState(null));
    } else {
      store.dispatch(setAuthState(response as TAuthInfo));
    }

    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
    return { ...appProps };
  },
);

export default customWrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Noting that currently in Next.js, `App` currently doesn't support Next.js Data Fetching methods like `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`.

`customWrapper` comes from this config:
https://blog.logrocket.com/use-redux-next-js/